# Folders Wrapping with Dynatree

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, dynatree

I have installed dynatree 1.2.4 on my web site to display a series of folders from an email archive solution. The folders are retrieved via AJAX and then formatted before the dynatree code is called

```
function folders_loaded(json) {
  $("#folder_list").html("<ul id=\"folder_list_ul\"></ul>");
  for (folder in json.allfolders) {
    processFolder(json.allfolders[folder], "folder_list_ul")
  }

  $("#folder_list").dynatree({
      onActivate: function (node) {
          //do stuff here
      },
      onClick: function (node, event) {
          //do stuff here
      }
  });
}
function processFolder(folder, target_id) {
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(folder));
  var fid = folder.folder_id;

  $("#" + target_id).append("<li id=\"folder_id_" + fid + "\"  class=\"folder\" data=\"folder_id: " + fid + "\">" + folder.name);
  $("#folder_id_" + folder.folder_id).append("<ul id=\"folder_list_" + fid + "\"></ul>")
  for(f in folder.folders) {
    processFolder(folder.folders[f],"folder_list_" + fid);
  } 
  $("#" + target_id).append("</li>");  
}
```

The function `processFolder` adds a list item to the target unordered list and then creates an another unordered list for the subfolders.  `processFolders` is then called again to process the subfolders.

Here is a part of the json object

```
{
   "allfolders":{
      "Calendar":{
         "folders":{},
         "folder_id":36,
         "name":"Calendar"
      },

      "INBOX":{
         "folders":{
            "Archive Folders":{
               "folders":{
                  "Emails Received 04-09-2008 to 01-09-2010 ":{
                     "folders":{ },
                     "folder_id":42,
                     "name":"Emails Received 04-09-2008 to 01-09-2010 "
                  },
                  "E-mails received 04-2005 to 05-2005":{
                     "folders":{},
                     "folder_id":43,
                     "name":"E-mails received 04-2005 to 05-2005"
                  },
               "folder_id":41,
               "name":"Archive Folders"
            }
         },
         "folder_id":40,
         "name":"INBOX"
      }
  }
}
```

The CSS for the folder_list div is as follows

```
#folder_list 
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:150px;

  height:100%;
  z-index:10;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

The folders render beautifully in Chrome, but with IE, folders with relatively long names wrap to the next line.

The image on the left shows what I see in IE, while the screenshot on the right shows Chrome.

[image: This is the screenshot from IE]         
[image: This is the screenshot from Chrome]

I've also tried adding `white-space:nowrap` to the list items in the folder_list div

```
#folder_list, #folder_list li
{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Has anyone seen this behavior in IE and what did you do to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code for the function processFolder?

Comment: I've added the function as well as a sample of the JSON data.

Comment: Tried to replicate your problem with the given code but got identical results in both IE10 and Chrome. I notice that the IE Chrome you have above has a horizontal scrollbar which suggests that x overflow is not hidden. Is that the same when you use IE? Also, what version of IE are you using?

Comment: I'm using IE9.  I found a JSFiddle site that used a similar code and it worked there.  The only difference I can think of is that this is being deployed on SharePoint and maybe there's some weird SharePoint CSS that's overriding the white-space CSS setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.  I had to add this to my CSS file.

```
ul.dynatree-container li>span 
{
  display:inline-block !important;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

The display piece seemed to be the biggest key to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

increase width and then try

```
#folder_list 
{
  width:180px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, increasing the width isn't an option.